# DOMContentLoaded is not firing inside browser extension Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, domcontentloaded

I am trying to create a Firefox Addon which will execute some code after page load. Here is my code:

```
var addBorder = function() {
    document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addBorder);
```

Unfortunately, it does not add any borders. On the other hand, I can change the border if I just place

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

inside my file.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code in a content script or background script?

Please share your extension manifest and the name of the script file that contains the code you posted.

Comment: Same problem: mine script run in "content_scripts"